# Umbraco - No url found for api name updateCheckApiBaseUrl, (anonymous)@ DependencyHandler.ax…avascript&cdv=1:740

Tags: iis, umbraco8

When publishing the Umbraco site, I get this error, the site works fine, but then when trying to login into the admin panel. The admin panel is almost empty, no text is displayed. only layout color.  (But the same admin panel works in a different server just fine.)

Errors

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 ()
No url found for api name updateCheckApiBaseUrl
Possibly unhandled rejection: No url found for api name backOfficeAssetsApiBaseUrl
Possibly unhandled rejection: No url found for api name tourApiBaseUrl
No url found for api name contentApiBaseUrl
Possibly unhandled rejection: No url found for api name sectionApiBaseUrl
```

[image]

And the admin panel looks like this.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the exact same problem than you and I found a solution on an old Umbraco v4 topic. **You simply need to clear your browser cookies.**

The post : https://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-8978

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + R didn't clear enough,  I used CC Cleaner and cleared everything with it, now working.

Comment: I had to clear the browser cookies and also restart the app.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what fixed it for me:

I had the following in my startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions
        {
            Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always
        });
    }
```

My staging site wasn't running over HTTPS, however as it wasn't in a development environment it was firing UseCookiePolicy() which was setting my cookies to be always 'secure'. I've commented out this part of the 'if else' condition which has resolved my issue. I'll of course reinstate it once I've established a one size fits all solution, but for now my CMS is back online.

Note: this was for a site running 10.4.